# Why is my line read not working as expected in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

I have the following code:

```sh
script_list=$'1 a\n2\n3'
old_IFS="${IFS}"
IFS=$'\n'
for line in "${script_list}"; do
    echo "__${line}__";
done
IFS="${old_IFS}"
```

which shall produce:

```sh
__1 a__
__2__
__3__
```

However, instead it gives me:

```sh
__1 a
2
3__
```

I double quoted `"${script_list}"` because it can contain spaces (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067297). But I believe this is also where the problem lies, because when I remove the double quotes around it, it works as expected.

What am I missing?

edit:
As Cyrus suggested, I ran the code at ShellCheck and it tells me:

```sh
$ shellcheck myscript
 
Line 5:
for line in "${script_list}"; do
            ^-- SC2066: Since you double quoted this, it will not word split, and the loop will only run once.
```

Is it safe to simply remove the double quotes or do I need to be careful with that?

Comment: You ask `Why is my line read not working as expected in bash?` so you have the answer `Since you double quoted this, it will not word split, and the loop will only run once`. || `Is it safe to simply remove the double quotes or do I need to be careful with that?` define "safe". It will be "safe" as in the loop will execute. But be aware of filename expansion. || Are you asking XY question?

Comment: It is safe as long as script_list doesn't contain globbing characters. But I have no idea what you're doing there. Why do you need this? What is the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I double quoted "${script_list}" because it can contain spaces*

This is only done to prevent the shell from splitting the string at spaces. However you explicitly tell the shell (by setting IFS) that your IFS is now a newline, not a space. The shell would split by default here on newlines, not on spaces, **unless** you quote it. Hence, remove the quotes.

Comment: Thanks! I did not knew about this yet. Here is the bash manual entry in case anyone else likes to look it up: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting